# Need a Macro to autofill down "x" rows after data input

Tags: excel, vba

Please if possible, could use some help with a Macro I have written out. The macro pastes a range of data to the active spreadsheet.I then have a inputbox that allows the user to input a selection into the first row of Column A in the new selection.  All I need is for the selection to paste down 3 rows of what they enter into instead of one( with formatting intact). I hope this makes sense and happy to clarify anything.

Thank for you any help you can give me.

Code Below:

```
Sub NewSection()

'adds a new section to the last row of the active spreadsheet'

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

    Set copySheet = Worksheets("zDATA")
    Set pasteSheet = ActiveSheet


    copySheet.Range("ClientSection").Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

'Text box for entering client name into the new section'
Dim ans As String, lr As Long
ans = InputBox("Enter Client Name", "Data Entry Form")
If ans = "" Then
    Exit Sub
Else
    lr = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Range("A" & lr).Value = ans
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You mean that `ans` should be pasted in A1,A2 and A3? or should be pasted at the end of the data, 3 times, each time in a row?

Comment: Thank you, The later in your resonse.. end of the data, for 3 rows in column A. I sadly cant identify the A cells since they will always be different numbers depending on where the section is entered.

Comment: Try: `Range("A" & lr, "A" & lr + 3).Value = ans`

Comment: According to your code, `lr` is 1 row below last row, so try `Range("A" & lr, "A" & lr + 2).Value = ans `.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you guys so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Virtual David and Foxfire!